# What are my options for streaming for silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, streaming

I would like to implement limited scope streaming (LAN, multicast, even broadcast) where the client is implemented in silverlight. More importantly, I would like to stream from a desktop OS, not a server OS. As a result, I can't use the MS media server, which I believe requires WS2003 or WS2008.

Ideally the solution would have some sort of API so I can plug in or provide a custom frame source.

If I need to encode my own video, how can I encode using H.264 or another Silverlight supported codec?

if I need to implement my own server, where can I find information about how a client starts to receive a stream?

thank you! I know, it's a lot of questions, but it basically boils down to "how do I stream from a non-server OS?"

Answer (score 0):

My Friend Vikram wrote a blog post about [Overview of Live Smooth Streaming,Live Encoding and Streaming with Expression Encoder 2 – Part 8](http://pendsevikram.blogspot.com/2009/04/overview-of-live-smooth-streaminglive.html). Check it out and see if it helps. I dont think he used a server for the article.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it, but I would rather not depend on using Expression Encoder...